# How can I make the camera safe zone lines easier to see?

Tags: interface, camera

[image]

How can I change the safe zone dotted line colors or transparency to make it easier to read?
I added a picture showing my issue and an image from the blender manual showing what am I hoping to see.
maybe if somebody knows the correct name of those dotted lines can be easier for me to find in the interface.

Comment: thanks, Jachym Michal, I already played around there and couldn't find it yet. any chance you know the specific name of the margin dotted lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preferences → Themes → 3D Viewport → View Overlay.

You can't make in darker, but it can be lighter and easy to see:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for digging through all the fields :).

Comment: thank you so much Jachym!! that is exactly it!  :D!